# Phase shift in hard sphere scattering

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering, scattering-cross-section

Consider scattering towards a hard sphere with radius a and potential (Assume ka=1):

$$ V(r) =\begin{cases}
      \infty , &r<a\\
      0 , &r>a \\
    \end{cases} $$

So first I determined the phase shifts for the first two partial waves $l= 0,1$ by applying boundary condition at $r=a$ and got:

$$ \tan \delta_l = \frac{j_l(ka)}{\eta_l(ka)} $$

Using that $ka=1$:

$$ \tan \delta_0 = \frac{\sin(1)/1}{-\cos(1)/1} = -\tan(1) \rightarrow \delta_0 = -1 $$
$$ \tan \delta_1 = \frac{ \frac{\sin(1)}{1} - \frac{\cos(1)}{1}  }{ -\frac{\cos(1)}{1} - \frac{\sin(1)}{1} } = \frac{ \sin(1) - \cos(1) }{ -\sin(1) - \cos(1) }  $$

So now when I try to compute the differential cross section including the first two partial waves, I get a bit of an ugly expression because of $\delta_1$:

$$ D(\theta) = | f(\theta)|^2 = \bigg| \frac{1}{k} \sum_{l=0}^{\infty} (2l+1)e^{i\delta_l} \sin(\delta_l) P_l(\cos(\theta)) \bigg|^2 $$
$$ D(\theta) = \bigg| \frac{1}{k} \biggl( e^{i\delta_0} \sin(\delta_0) + 3e^{i\delta_1} \sin(\delta_1) \cos(\theta) \biggr)  \bigg|^2 $$

Is there any other way to approach the problem to get a better expression for the differential cross section?